# How can I change the background of views inside a recyclerview for certain items?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

So essentially, I have a recyclerview that has a list of levels. But essentially, I want certain items to have a black colored background to suggest that they are not locked yet.(kind of like in video games)

my current method:

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(BracketsAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
        // Get the data model based on position
        Bracket bracket = bracketsList.get(position);
        int color = UserPreferences.getInstance().getBracket();

        // Set item views based on your views and data model
        TextView textView = viewHolder.nameTextView;
        textView.setText(bracket.toString());
        Log.d("Bracket level", ""+bracket.getId());
        if(color < bracket.getId()) {
            textView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.black); // suggests level is locked
        }

    }
```

The issue with this method, is that it works initially but the moment I scroll down and back up, items that should not be colored end up being colored. Why is this? Is there a better way of implementing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recycle view always reuses the old view so you are getting that problem, To solve the problem, you should set color every time calling bindViewHolder, So try to do like this,

```
if(color < bracket.getId()) {
    textView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.black); // suggests level is locked
} else {
    textView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.defaultcolor); // default color
}
```

this will work fine.

Comment: Good catch. I should have read more about how recyclerview works.